# What is the function of git bash for windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, git-bash

Is git bash something that can be used as a windows alternative to terminal on ubuntu? Can we use cmd.exe for the same purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git bash exists as a minimal environment for running git on Windows.  Git itself consists of a number of shell and Perl scripts as well as binaries. In order to run them you need an environment that can interpret shell scripts.  A Windows command prompt can only interpret Batch files.

Note that git bash doesn't have much more than the shell, git, ls, and a few other utilities. If you need a more complete shell and tool suite then look at https://www.cygwin.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Git BASH provides a BASH emulation used to run Git from the command line. Unix users should feel right at home, as the BASH emulation behaves just like the "git" command in LINUX and UNIX environments.

Also it is used to run commands of Linux such as ls,cd etc. If you want to use commands in Windows go install GIT BASH.

You cannot use command prompt for same purpose.